Implementation of a Custom Loss Function in Keras for a Multi-item Newsvendor Problem with Substitutions
I want to implement a custom loss function in Keras for a Newsvendor. Problem (Demand forecasting and problem solving integrated in one ANN). The challenging part is that I have multiple products with customer substitution. That means, that if a stock-out for one product appears, the open demand can be covered by an other product at a certain percentage (I have a substituion matrix for this).
For this the loss function has to take all output variables into account. Is there a way how I can implement this loss function nicely?
Loss function
Custom loss function adapted for vectorized critical ratios and substitution matrix
def newsvendor_quantile_loss_with_substitution(u, o, y_true, y_pred, alpha):

    # Cast numpy arrays to tensors
    u = tf.convert_to_tensor(u, dtype=tf.float32) #underage costs
    o = tf.convert_to_tensor(o, dtype=tf.float32) #overage costs
    alpha = tf.convert_to_tensor(alpha, dtype=tf.float32) #substitution matrix
    
    # Calculate unmet demand for each product
    unmet_demand = tf.maximum(0.0, y_pred - y_true)

    # Calculate the demand increase for each product due to substitutions from other products
    demand_increase = tf.zeros(6, dtype=tf.float32)
    for i in range(6):
        demand_increase = unmet_demand[i] * alpha[i]
    #demand_increase = tf.tensordot(alpha, unmet_demand, axes=[[0], [0]])

    # Adjusted demand is the original demand plus the increase due to substitutions
    adjusted_demand = y_true + demand_increase

    # Compute the loss with adjusted demand
    loss = -tf.reduce_mean(u * y_pred - (u + o) * tf.maximum(y_pred - adjusted_demand, 0))
    return loss

This loss function works but has a terrible bad output.

terrible bad output in what way?
